# Simple if then else then using ? :

Tags: c#

How can I write this?

```
match = p.PType.Type == EPType.Umbr
                        ? matchShouldBeThis
                        : (p.IsShare == true ? matchShouldBeThisInstead);
```

Compiler complains that it wants another :

Basically its a
i
then
else if

Comment: Use a vanilla if/else?

Comment: There is no `?` operator in C#. There is `??` and `?:` What do you want with `p.IsShare == true ? _Iwantthisinstead` exactly?

Comment: For this, I would likely stick to class if/else for readability.

Comment: ok I think your right

Comment: `== true` is always redundant when dealing with Booleans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to write out your code without shorthand syntax first, then see if it can be "simplified" using `?:`.

It seems you want `_Iwantthisinsteadwant` when `p.PType.Type == EPType.Umbr` *and* `p.IsShare == true`, otherwise you want `thisone`.

This will become:

```
if (p.PType.Type == EPType.Umbr && p.IsShare)
{
    match = _Iwantthisinsteadwant;
}
else
{
    match = thisOne;
}
```

This can be shortened to:

```
match = (p.PType.Type == EPType.Umbr && p.IsShare)
    ? _Iwantthisinstead
    : thisOne;
```

Comment: `== true` is always redundant.

Comment: @Rik Well, I _almost_ always prefer to use `p.IsShare` instead of `p.IsShare == true` also but I couldn't call that as _redundant_ `:)`. This is totally matter of taste. You can see a lot `== true` usage in .NET Framework source code for example. For a beginner programmer `p.IsShare == true` is clearly more readable\understandable than `p.IsShare` in my opinion.

Comment: @SonerGönül Well, it's always redundant in a semantic sense. It only helps in readability when it's not clear you're dealing with a Boolean, in which case I would argue that would be the issue to address.

Answer (score 0):

Your second condition is missing `false part`

`match = p.PType.Type == EPType.Umbr
                        ? thisOne
                        : (p.IsShare ? _Iwantthisinstead : false);`

Comment: does this not return false to the match variable?